# reshape and rearrange string into specific shape

Tags: javascript, arrays, reshape

On the function below, I'm trying to reshape a string into W-like shape, and made a new output with new arrangement based on its `totalLevel`, check the test case at the end of the script for more clarity. I'm using `nodejs`, and came up with idea using objects. But I have no clue on how to take the next `str[i]` after it reach the `totalLevel`. Thanks for any helps!

```
function shapeOfW (str, totalLevel) {
var obj = {}
var position = 0

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            obj[position+1] = (str[i])
            position++
                if (posisi == totalLevel) {
                    break
                }

    }

return obj
}

//TEST CASE
console.log (shapeOfW('ABCDEFG', 3))//AEBDFCG

/*
    Input           : ABCDE
    Transformed into:   1| A       E
                        2|   B   D   F
                        3|     C       G

    OUTPUT          : AEBDFCG               
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bidimensional array (an array of arrays) instead of an object to better represent a bidimensional space positioning of your letters (with x and y coordinates).

Here is an example (with a bonus formatted console.log);

```js
function shapeOfW(str, totalLevel) {
  var array = [];
  var stepY = 1;

  for (var x = 0, y = 0; x < str.length; x += 1, y += stepY) {
    array[y] = array[y] || str.split('').map(() => ".");
    array[y][x] = str[x];
    if (x && x % (totalLevel - 1) === 0) {
      stepY = -stepY;
    }
  }

  return array;
}

function consoleLog(array) {
  const log = array.map(arr => arr.join(' ')).join('\n');
  console.log(log);
}

function join(array) {
  const log = array.map(arr => arr.filter(i => i !== '.').join('')).join('');
  console.log(log);
}

//TEST CASE
consoleLog(shapeOfW('ABCDEFG', 3))
join(shapeOfW('ABCDEFG', 3))

/*
Input           : ABCDE
Transformed into:   1| A       E
                    2|   B   D   F
                    3|     C       G

OUTPUT          : AEBDFCG               
*/
```